# Strange border with custom box-shadow and focus indicator

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I made [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/fh7anL1b/1/) with two number inputs with custom outline and box-shadow.
In Google Chrome I see strange black-gray border after focus on bottom input element.

[image]

For this input I use

```css
                  .shadowBox:focus {
                    outline: 1px black dotted !important;
                    box-shadow: 1px 1px grey;                    
                  }
```

If I set `box-shadow: none` this strange border doesn`t appear. What I do wrong?

[image]

**EDITED**. Why this "strange border" appears on 'focus' if I use box-shadow? This border exists only in Google Chrome, but not in Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have both, the dotted outline And border solid you can have this instead:

```
.shadowBox:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted black;
  border: 2px black solid;
}
```

Comment: I mean about that,  why this "strange border" appears on 'focus' if I use box-shadow? This border exists only in Google Chrome, not in Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Well, it is not strange at all. You are using  the focus selector, which gives the properties you want, once the input is clicked. You can set whatever properties you want. In this case if you don't want that "strange" border as you call it, simply add border: none and that border will disappear.

Comment: If I clicked input with `box-shadow: null` this border doesn't appear. You mean, that need to explicitly set border properties for custom focus, may be at least for Google Chrome? What I may do with this border If I want to make input element with focus like in Mozilla Firefox?